# Do we know if any other foods can be hydrated?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-ii

In *Back to the Future II*, we see Grandma Lorraine [rehydrate a pizza](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Dehydrated_pizza) - very well too I might add.  The tool used for this is a [hydrator](http://backtothefuture.wikia.com/wiki/Hydrator).  Looking at the linked article for a hydrator on Futurepedia, though, there is only reference to it being used for a pizza.  It wouldn't really make much sense if it was only usable on pizzas though - **do we know of any *other* foods in *Back to the Future* sources (canon and non-canon accepted) that can also be dehydrated and rehydrated?**

Comment: I guess Futurepedia only lists pizza because that is all we see - it does make sense that the hydrator can hydrate more than that - unless the only food eaten in the future is pizza (other than fresh fruit)

Comment: @HorusKol Futurepedia doesn't (AFAIK) cover the cartoon series, which I haven't actually seen and wondered perhaps if something was mentioned there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly seems very likely.  When she puts the pizza into the hydrator, she says "Hydrate level 4 please":

This suggests that the device is capable of rehydrating a wide range of products.  I have not been able to find any references to exactly what these other food products might be.

Comment: Really, how much skill is there in telling a machine to rehydrate a pizza at level four?

Comment: @N_Soong - I reckon Neelix could muck it up.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [BTTF 2 novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0425118754), you can also hydrate...erm...smaller pizzas.

> Grandma Lorraine stuck one of those expandable pizzas in the Hydrator
>   - **a real four-incher!** That was one thing you could say about Marty McFly Senior’s parents: They weren’t cheap.
>
> 'so I thought,’ she continued cheerily as she distributed the plates,
>   ‘it would be nice if we threw a little party for him.’
>
> The Hydrator beeped. His mother bustled happily back to the machine,
>   pulling the now fifteen-inch pizza free. And she was nice enough not
>   to mention that it had taken the Hydrator a full twelve-second cycle
>   to finish their dinner - Marty wished he could afford one of those new
>   six-second models.

Even if it can only be used for pizza, this would also explain why the hydrator has variable settings since not all sizes of pizza would need the same level of hydration.

---

Additionally, the [concept art](http://www.eeyth.com/back-to-the-future-ii/jm4yx2tfiixzbrtd9vc5oij8ur9kyy) for the film describes it as a "**PIZZA HYDRATOR**". This is hardly conclusive, but it is at least strongly suggestive that that is what it's main purpose is.

[image]

And the officially licensed BTTF card game also refers to it as a "*Pizza Hydrator*"

[image]

Comment: Ah, specialized gadgets... they did a good job of projecting just how ridiculous it was going to get.